# How to preserve the equations alignment in addition to controlling the columns spacing across different nested aligning environements?

Tags: alignat

In this MWE, I need to preserve the equations alignment at both prescribed positions (i.e. equal signs and `\text{}`) while controlling the columns spacing (i.e. `\qquad`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
%
a &= 1 & \qquad &\text{in } \Omega\\
b &= 2 &&\text{on } \Gamma_1\\
%
\shortintertext{and}
%
\begin{alignedat}{2}
c &= 3 && \text{on } \Gamma_2\\
d &= 4 && \text{on } \Gamma_3\\
\end{alignedat}
%
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you nesting `alignedat`?

Comment: @egreg I would like to (1) control the columns spacing in addition to (2) assigning a single equation number to a set of equations. So, that is the first solution came to my mind. You are welcome to enhance my answer as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

More of a hack than a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
%
a &= 1 & \quad &\text{in } \Omega\\
b &= 2 &&\text{on } \Gamma_1\\
%
\shortintertext{and}
%
\MoveEqLeft[-2.95]\mathclap{\begin{alignedat}{2}
c &= 3 &\qquad&\mkern2mu \text{on } \Gamma_2\\
d &= 4 && \mkern2mu\text{on } \Gamma_3
\end{alignedat}}
%
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit* :

A somewhat neater solution consists in adding `\notag` for the last two alignments and an empty (numbered) alignment between these last two, compensating for the supplementary vertical spacing:

```
   \begin{alignat}{2}
    %
    a &= 1 & \quad &\text{in } Ω\\
    b &= 2 &&\text{on } \Gamma₁\\
    %
    \shortintertext{and}
       c &= 3 &&\text{on } \Gamma₂ \notag\\[-0.5\baselineskip]
        & \\[-0.5\baselineskip]
    d &= 4 && \text{on } \Gamma₃ \notag
    %
    \end{alignat}
```

[image]

Comment: The second edit is pretty nice but it will affect the equation display when clicking on its cross-reference in the text since it would display only the dummy equation and below not the whole set of equations.